# How does the software know whether we sent the transaction to a smart contract or EOA

Tags: transactions, contract-design

When we send a transaction to an address it can be EOA/smart contract, so how does the software know which is what?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the address contains a code payload

- With `EXTCODESIZE` op code in Solidity
- With `web3.eth.getCode()` over JSON-RPC